# Error during creating Invoice from Appointment

Tags: acumatica

Please can anyone answer. 
I have a problem during creating Invoice from Appointment which has Bill to Customer different from Customer of the Appointment.

Error: An error occurred during processing of the field Account value 2869 Error: 'TaskID' cannot be found in the system.

And I have no idea what can course this issue

Comment: Provide more information please!

Comment: This can happen if your field (TaskID) in this case is not found in the selectable values. If you look at the query for the selector you can find the where condition to know why the TaskID value is not valid. Also the TaskID value might not exist as a Task anymore. Without any code details for something you are trying to troubleshoot this doesn't appear to be a programming question more just a question for an issue you are running into in general.